# Clear JQuery DataTable Local Storage

Tags: datatables, local-storage

How to clear Jquery Datatable Local Storage programmatically?

localstorage.clear() clears all localstorage.

But I need to clear the datatable values specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt RefreshButtonDataTable" onclick="ClearDataTableStorageAndRefresh()"></i>
     <script>
          function ClearDataTableStorageAndRefresh() {
              ClearLocalStorageDataTables_tbl();
               $('#tbl_SearchTasks').DataTable().ajax.reload();
           }
     </script>



function ClearLocalStorageDataTables_tbl() {
    debugger;
    var arr = []; // Array to hold the keys
    // Iterate over localStorage and insert the keys that meet the condition into arr
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage.key(i).substring(0, 14) == 'DataTables_tbl') {
            arr.push(localStorage.key(i));
        }
    }

    // Iterate over arr and remove the items by key
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        localStorage.removeItem(arr[i]);
    }

    new Noty({
        type: 'success',
        theme: 'metroui',
        layout: 'bottomRight',
        text: 'Datatable Temporary Storage Cleared',
        progressBar: true,
        timeout: 5000
    }).show();
}
```